# Are questions involving Jack London's Universe off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions involving Jack London's universe(one in the Call of the Wild and White Fang) off Topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think either of those could be considered Science Fiction or Fantasy, so the answer is "Yes" - questions about that universe would be off-topic.

Comment: [Jack London's SF](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/london_jack) was only a small part of his huge output, and it wasn't what he was best known for. So questions about his non-SF works would be off-topic. Questions about _[The Star Rover](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1162)_ or _[The Iron Heel](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1164)_ would be on-topic, though.

Comment: @sjl - if you can expand on why the latter are SciFi (I'm not familiar with them), this comment should become an answer.

Comment: @DVK The descriptions of the books in Wikipedia make solid cases for both being SF.

Comment: If he were best known as a writer of science fiction and fantasy, would his non-SF work then be on topic? For instance are questions about Asimov's mysteries & non-fiction on topic?

Comment: @user14111 - yes, they are offtopic